# Silverstripe 3.1: Adding link to has_one in CMS

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

When using has_many's or many_many's it is easy in Silverstripe to navigate from one DataObject to the other. But now I would like the same functionality for the has_one's: Add a link to the selected dataobject in the CMS. In this case the format of a has_one in the CMS will become the following:
Title - Dropdown with values - clickable link to selected object.

Is there a way to do this? I don't mind the breadcrumb path to break, or that you'd first have to save in order to show the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of approaches here:

I'm assuming you use a GridField for the has_many or many_many lists? If you want to use the same approach, create a temporary list with just the has_one record and use this as the source of the GridField. Use the GridFieldConfig_Base or GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor as the config so you can add or remove the new records. Add the link in the $summary_fields array of your has_one record so it appears on the GridField.

Second (and easier) approach is to add a LiteralField after where you has_one record field is to output the link to the record.

What do you think?

Comment: Your second solution sounds just perfect. But I was under the impression that you can't put a LiteralField behind another field?

Comment: Not behind, just after it. Use $fields->insertAfter($literalField, "has_one_title");

Comment: That would mean it shows up on the next line, or is there a way to change that?

Comment: No easy way I know of, unless you extend whatever field you are using, and create a new template file which will be used to output the field and the link beside it.

Comment: Ok, I had some problems lately with changing admin templates (leftAndMain), and I ended up just overwriting the templates in the core of the cms module. So I probably will just settle for adding it below the has_one. Thanks!

Comment: I thought you would. It's the easiest approach.